# Why does arduino work on usb power?

Tags: power, voltage-level, electricity, electronics

The arduino website states that the operating voltage of an arduino is 7-12V.

Why does the arduino work powered on just usb then? As usb only outputs 5V and 500ma.

Is it preferable to say run the arduino on an external 9V dc power source, or does it make no difference?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The arduino website states that the operating voltage of an arduino is 7-12V.

That's when it goes through the voltage regulator. It's a *linear regulator*, meaning it wastes a lot of power as heat. The regulator outputs 5V that's given to the MCU. The USB voltage bypasses the regulator and goes to a fuse before going to the common 5V for the board. If less than 7V is given to the regulator, it will produce less than 5V.

> Is it preferable to say run the arduino on an external 9V dc power source, or does it make no difference?

Usually, yes. A 9V supply would give you more than 500ma, giving you flexibility to add higher current components like motors and lots of LEDs. It will make no difference if you have a single LED connected.

Comment: Although you wouldn't want to run *too* much off the built-in regulator...

Comment: @Ignacio, true, but IIRC it's over an amp vs 500ma *max*... also if you use the 9V directly for sensors.

Comment: this may seem like a dumb question but will the following be a sound power supply for the arduino? http://thepihut.com/products/7-port-usb-hub-for-the-raspberry-pi  I have a 9V 1A PSU also, not sure which is the best to power it off. Or are both sound bets?

Comment: @c_breeez I can't advise you because I don't know anything about your situation.

Comment: Note that while a 9V power supply may be reasonable, future readers should not confuse that with a small 9v battery, a very low current device.  In terms of the regulator's capability there are two issues - one is a current rating, but often the more important one is a thermal rating for dissipated power, and that depends on the difference between input and regulated voltages as well as the current drawn.  The higher the supply voltage above the minimum, the less current the regulator can pass without overheating. High current projects should use a distinct regulator for peripheral loads.

Comment: @AnnonomusPenguin im running two arduino s one powering 8 300 micro amp ir detectors and one ir led. The other 6 detectors and one ir led. I'm also running a innovations id12la rfid reader on another port. And a wifi dongle. So yeah those four things one on each port. A mega, an uno, a wifi dongle and an rfid reader

Comment: @c_breez as long as the RFID reader and the wifi dongle comply with USB 2.0 specifications (no reason why they shouldn't), then the USB hub should be plenty fine. I'd be surprised if the Arduinos used 1/10th of an amp... the only thing is I think the Pi might need to be powered on for power to be delivered to the devices...

Comment: @AnnonomusPenguin Awesome thanks a lot of the input and reassuring me on this, just wanting to make sure I get the power requirements right for my project. I just tested the hub out and it will power arduinos without the pi being connected, as it runs off a DC adapter. Thanks a lot for the help